# UTF-8 decoding error in Python

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm trying to do this in Python: `'Fi\xc3\xb1a'.decode('utf-8')`

I expect the result to be `Fiña`. But the result is actually: `u'Fi\xf1a'`

No idea what is going on, some help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't call it an "error" if you don't fully understand it. Chances are you are just misinterpreting the situation (like it is the case here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the correct result, the Unicode codepoint for `ñ` is U+00f1. It's just that Python won't display the Unicode character directly. Try it in a `print` statement and see what you get.